# Comma usage in thanking a person for multiple actions: "thank you for doing A, and for doing B"

Tags: commas

I am writing the Acknowledgments section in my thesis. Which, if any, of the following is correct?

1. "Jane Doe, thank you for caring for your students as people and for always taking the time to chat with me."
2. "Jane Doe, thank you for caring for your students as people, and for always taking the time to chat with me."

Comment: Welcome to the site. We like to see evidence of your own research before answering the questions that relate to what you do not understand even after researching. Your question is not complex so really belongs in https://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'd go so far as to use a dash – signalling a really genuine pause for reflexion. But comma, zero punctuation ... ellipsis even – all work.